# installed php71w-gd and getting error GD Library extension not available with this PHP installation

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, centos, php-gd

I am using laravel web framework on centos 7 server and nginx web server, I installed php71w-gd and still getting this error when i want to upload a file

```
Intervention \ Image \ Exception \ NotSupportedException
GD Library extension not available with this PHP installation.
```

you may need to know this

```
# php -i | grep gd
/etc/php.d/gd.ini,
gd
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning => 1 => 1
```

Comment: Did you restart nginx after install and enable gd?

Comment: yes, but error is still there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it by reinstalling php71 and php-gd from ["Remi's RPM repository"](https://rpms.remirepo.net/) by running this code.

```
# yum --enablerepo=remi-php71 install php-gd
```

after that you should restart nginx and php-fpm:

```
# systemctl restart nginx
# systemctl restart php-fpm
```

Also look at [How to Install PHP 7, NGINX & MySQL 5.6 on CentOS/RHEL 7.4 & 6.9](https://tecadmin.net/install-php-7-nginx-mysql-5-on-centos/#)
if you have any problem in installing and configuring your server for laravel.

Comment: If you use "remi-php71" repository, I recommend that you enable it permanently (it only provides PHP), so you won't encounter issue when trying to install another extension, as explained in https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/

Answer (score 3):

@Hamed Abdollahi please check follwing steps,

The GD Graphics Library is for dynamically manipulating images. For Ubuntu you should install it manually:

```
PHP5: sudo apt-get install php5-gd
PHP7.0: sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd
PHP7.1: sudo apt-get install php7.1-gd
PHP7.2: sudo apt-get install php7.2-gd
```

That's all, you can verify that GD support loaded:

```
php -i | grep -i gd
```

Output should be like this:

```
GD Support => enabled
GD headers Version => 2.1.1-dev
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning => 0 => 0
```

Comment: Thanks @Mayur but as I said, I already installed php71w-gd on my CentOS server, but still getting the same error.

Comment: I am seeing ,  gd.jpeg_ignore_warning => 1 => 1 . Is this a problem ? How can we make it 0